# How to update async await function when a variable change?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, highcharts

```js
genderPie()

let filter = {};


async function genderPie() {
  const d = await getData();
  const g = await d.reduce((a, o) => (o.GEN && a.push(o.GEN), a), []);
  const gender = Object.keys(g).length;
  const m = await d.reduce((a, o) => (o.GEN == 1 && a.push(o.GEN), a), []);
  const male = Object.keys(m).length;
  const f = await d.reduce((a, o) => (o.GEN == 2 && a.push(o.GEN), a), []);
  const female = Object.keys(f).length;


  var data = [{
    name: 'male',
    y: male,
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'female',
    y: female,
    id: 2
  }];

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        innerSize: '80%',
        dataLabels: {
          connectorWidth: 0
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      "data": data,
      type: 'pie',
      animation: false,
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(event) {
            filter.GEN = '' + this.id + '';
          }
        }
      }
    }],
    "chart": {
      "renderTo": "gender"
    },
  });
}

async function getData() {

  buildFilter = (filter) => {
    let query = {};
    for (let keys in filter) {
      if (filter[keys].constructor === Array && filter[keys].length > 0) {
        query[keys] = filter[keys];
      }
    }
    return query;
  }

  //FILTER DATA

  //Returns the filtered data
  filterData = (dataset, query) => {
    const filteredData = dataset.filter((item) => {
      for (let key in query) {
        if (item[key] === undefined || !query[key].includes(item[key])) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
    return filteredData;
  };


  //FETCH JSON
  const dataset = [{
      "GEN": "2"
    }, {
      "GEN": "1"
    }, {
      "GEN": "1"
    }, {
      "GEN": "2"
    },
    {
      "GEN": "2"
    }, {
      "GEN": "2"
    }, {
      "GEN": "2"
    }, {
      "GEN": "1"
    }
  ]

  //BUILD THE FILTER
  const query = buildFilter(filter);
  const result = filterData(dataset, query);
  console.log(result)
  return result

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>



<div id="gender"></div>
```

does anyone can explain me how to handle the following?

I have two functions that filter data and than I build a chart with Hichart
Each time a user click for example a slice of a pie chart an event is fired and an object is populated.
That object allows me to filter the dataset and redraw the chart

The last thing I'm missing is about to update the filtering functions based on the object to be populated

first I'll do this

```
        async function getData() {
  buildFilter = (filter) => {
    let query = {};
    for (let keys in filter) {
        if (filter[keys].constructor === Array && filter[keys].length > 0) {
            query[keys] = filter[keys];
        }
    }
    return query;
  }
```

then

```
  filterData = (data, query) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter( (item) => {
        for (let key in query) {
            if (item[key] === undefined || !query[key].includes(item[key])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    return filteredData;
};

const query = buildFilter(filter);
const result =  filterData(data, query);
```

my object is

```
let filter = {}
```

when a user click the slice myobject become for example

```
let filter = {
gen: "1"
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the prompt replay. I never used jsfiddle or alike and when put the code it diden't work. Does it block async or whatelse?

Comment: tried but seems it wan't call the function. It says function not defined even if it is. For sure I'm doiing smething wrong but I don't know what

Comment: done, it seems ok but stil get error.

Comment: here we go https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lpdlbt

Comment: I changed it, anyway https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lpdlbt I add the console log and hard code partial data

Comment: OK, so what is your desired effect when a slice is clicked?

Comment: yes, when a slice is clicked I would like to add GEN: "1" into the flter, and this I got it. After that I would like that the overall dataset will be filtered so that the chart will drow only data regarding what the click add in the filter. Let me know if I'm not clear, it could be :-)

Comment: So, when I click "male", you want the pie to become 100% male, right?

Comment: exactly. What I actually don't know how to handle is the update of th dataset to become filtered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qhn1tg).

In `getData()`, I simplified your filter to this one:

```
return data.filter(item => {
    for (const property of Object.keys(filter)) {
        if (item[property] !== filter[property]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

and when a slice is clicked, I call `genderPie()` again, after updating the `filter`.

You might want to separate the data request from the filtering, so that the data is downloaded only once, not every time a filter is changed.

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for the help. As you can imagine my attempt is to reduce the dataset so other related chart will be based on the new dataset. Each chart  will have the same click event that add a new filter.  this means that i have to add that pice f code within each chart correct?

Comment: I think the code I posted here will be written only once. All charts will share the same data. Every time you click at a piece of any chart, you will have to apply the filter and then remake all charts.

Comment: ok. really many thanks. i was struggling in how to achieve this. Now I'l give it a try with other chart. many thanks again

Comment: ok, the only issue on that is that at the end of drawPie we are appending the chart to a specific div for each chart. While introducing a second chart it wan't be visible couse the div is already taken by the other chart

Comment: Use a different div for each pie. You can create divs dynamically and put them in the document body, if you don't want them to be there from the beginning.

Comment: okok you are righ. I have to work it out but I'm really near thanks to your help